# The Semantic HTML way for a buttons list?

Tags: html, semantic-ui, semantics, semantic-markup

Let's say I have a list of buttons that filter content by category

```
<nav>
  <p>Please select your category:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button>Cats</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button>Dogs</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button>Lizards</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button>Chupacabras</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Is the `<nav>` element the right component?
Should the `<p>` be a heading instead?

I know that `<input>` fields can be in a group inside `<fieldset>`, with a `<legend>` on top, but is this applicable to the above example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your code. But in my opinion you dont need but better you should not to wrap in a nav tag. A div tag would be enough.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav

> The  HTML element represents a section of a page whose purpose is
> to provide navigation links, either within the current document or to
> other documents. Common examples of navigation sections are menus,
> tables of contents, and indexes.

```html
<div class="filter-buttons">
  <p>Please select your category:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button>Cats</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button>Dogs</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button>Lizards</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button>Chupacabras</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I would go beyond "don't need" to "should not" since the nav isn't wrapping navigation elements.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a filter as you say, you shouldn't use a navigation element. The [`<nav>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav) "represents a section of a page whose purpose is to provide navigation links". Filter buttons are not links.

If you're asking users to select one option out of a set of options, an array of radio buttons or a [`<select>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) seems most appropriate. This would also allow you to semantically tie the field label to the field.

```html
<label for="filter-categories">Filter by category</label>:
<select id="filter-categories">
  <option value="all">All Animals</option>
  <option value="cats">Cats</option>
  <option value="dogs">Dogs</option>
  <option value="lizards">Lizards</option>
  <option value="chupacabras">Chupacabras</option>
</select>
```

It's hard to know without further context though.